# Is there a way to tell TypeScript to use less common type without explicit type declaration?

Tags: typescript

I'm trying to work with type and generics, so I came up with this:

```
type TypeMap = {
  "string": string,
  "number": number
}

type IndexedType<Key extends keyof TypeMap> = TTypeMap[Key];

function testFunc<Key extends keyof TypeMap>(key: Key, item: IndexedType<Key>) {
  // ...
}
```

When I pass first argument as literal or primitive constant, type of item variable is indexed correctly from the map:

```
const key = "number";

// OK
testFunc("number", 5);

// OK
testFunc(key, 5);

// Will throw a type error
testFunc("string", 5);
```

However, when I'm using a variable in object type, it infers the best common type, so the type will be just string.

```
const key = { value: "string" };

// Will not work at all
testFunc(key.value, 5);
```

Is there a way to tell TypeScript to use less common type without explicit type declaration? I'm trying to use an object with the type as config to infer the output of the function the same way through generics, so declaring the same thing twice (as a literal and the type) will result in much messier code, and requiring to change both the type and the variable declaration when config is changed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This code:

```
const key = { value: "string" };

// Will not work at all
testFunc(key.value, 5);
```

should work if you change the `key` declaration to:

```
const key = { value: "string" } as const;
```

or:

```
const key = { value: "string" as const };
```

(i.e. make the whole object or just the value of `value` a const type.)

See the documentation:

- https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-3-4.html#const-assertions

Also, TypeScript 5.0 introduced the `const` type modifier, that can be used on the function definition instead of the variable declarations, but I'm not sure if that could work here unless you passed the entire object to the function. But here is more info just in case you can use it:

- https://devblogs.microsoft.com/typescript/announcing-typescript-5-0/#const-type-parameters
- https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-5-0.html#const-type-parameters

Comment: Thank you! Also finded a way to solve this using Object.freeze() call, however, this does not work deeply with nested objects